# Why ldd produces different result for the same file in different directories?

Tags: qt, deployment, shared-libraries, ldd

I was trying to deploy a Qt/QML application for Linux. Something strange occured that the target system complained about undefined symbol in `libQt5Widget.so.5`, while I had copied all the Qt-related libraries shown up in `ldd -r` result of that file, and `ldd -r` on target system said there's no "not found" libraries.

After some time I discovered that even `ldd -r` in my own system spotted undefined symbols. When I `ldd -r` the same file in Qt installation directory, however, no undefined symbols were found.

The output looked like this:

```
wyl8899@Ubuntu:~/deploy/Qt_Libraries$ ldd -r libQt5Widgets.so.5
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffd1409a000)
    libQt5Gui.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5 (0x00007faac833d000)
    libQt5Core.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5 (0x00007faac7c97000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007faac7a79000)
(... and much more)
    libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007faac0d13000)
    libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007faac0b0d000)
undefined symbol: _ZNK19QAbstractTableModel7siblingEiiRK11QModelIndex   (./libQt5Widgets.so.5)
undefined symbol: _ZTI17QPixmapIconEngine   (./libQt5Widgets.so.5)
undefined symbol: _ZN17QPixmapIconEngine5paintEP8QPainterRK5QRectN5QIcon4ModeENS5_5StateE   (./libQt5Widgets.so.5)
(... and much more)

wyl8899@Ubuntu:~/deploy/Qt_Libraries$ ldd -r /opt/Qt/5.5/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff4b5e5000)
    libQt5Gui.so.5 => /opt/Qt/5.5/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5 (0x00007ff5e3978000)
    libQt5Core.so.5 => /opt/Qt/5.5/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5 (0x00007ff5e3233000)
(... and much more)
    libdrm.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2 (0x00007ff5dcdad000)
    libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007ff5dcba9000)
    libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007ff5dc9a3000)
```

Also I noticed that the number of libraries shown differs. I would like to know what caused `ldd -r` produces different result for the same file in different directories. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, but I'd say that in the first case `ldd` picks up your system Qt libraries:

- `libQt5Core.so.5` in **`/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`**
- `libQt5Gui.so.5` in **`/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`**

and they don't have required symbols. In the second case `ldd` picks up Qt libraries which are in the same directory as pointed `libQt5Widgets.so.5`:

- `libQt5Core.so.5` in **`/opt/Qt/5.5/gcc_64/lib/`**
- `libQt5Gui.so.5` in **`/opt/Qt/5.5/gcc_64/lib/`**

and they do have required symbols.